# How to add style sheet to confirm box?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> 
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> 
</button>
```

I want to attach this `<div class="box box-solid box-success">...</div>` code to my confirm box. I try several ways but not success. I do this code using Laravel 5 and a Blade template.

plz, this question is deferent , because i used to code larave 5 php framework.I used blade template format. so , i used like this syntax .

```
 <p id='buttons'>
            {!! Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary','onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure?")']) !!} &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 
            {!! Form::button('Cancel', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}

        </p>
```

Comment: `confirm() alert` cannot be styled. You can use `jquery dialog box instead`

Comment: You can use Sweet Alert: [link](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, I prefer you should use Modal of boot strap 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Or if you want to easily use of modal of bootstrap, you can use bootbox:
http://bootboxjs.com/

It has sample about how using confirm modal in example

Answer (score -1):

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"> 
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> 
</button>
```

CSS:

```
#modalContainer {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:10000;
    background-image:url(tp.png); /* required by MSIE to prevent actions on lower z-index elements */
}

#alertBox {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    min-height:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:20px 30px;
}

#modalContainer > #alertBox {
    position:fixed;
}

#alertBox h1 {
    margin:0;
    font:bold 0.9em verdana,arial;
    background-color:#3073BB;
    color:#FFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    padding:2px 0 2px 5px;
}

#alertBox p {
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-left:55px;
}

#alertBox #closeBtn {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin:5px auto;
    padding:7px;
    border:0 none;
    width:70px;
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:#357EBD;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* unrelated styles */

#mContainer {
    position:relative;
    width:600px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:5px;
    border-top:2px solid #000;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
}

h1,h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:4px;
    font:bold 1.5em verdana;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

code {
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#069;
}

#credits {
    position:relative;
    margin:25px auto 0px auto;
    width:350px; 
    font:0.7em verdana;
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    height:90px;
    padding-top:4px;
}

#credits img {
    float:left;
    margin:5px 10px 5px 0px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    width:80px;
    height:79px;
}

.important {
    background-color:#F5FCC8;
    padding:2px;
}

code span {
    color:green;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var ALERT_TITLE = "Oops!";
var ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT = "Ok";

if(document.getElementById) {
    window.confirm = function(txt) {
        createCustomConfirm(txt);
    }
}

function createCustomConfirm(txt) {
    d = document;

    if(d.getElementById("modalContainer")) return;

    mObj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    mObj.id = "modalContainer";
    mObj.style.height = d.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";

    confirmObj = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    confirmObj.id = "alertBox";
    if(d.all && !window.opera) confirmObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
    confirmObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - confirmObj.offsetWidth)/2 + "px";
    confirmObj.style.visiblity="visible";

    h1 = confirmObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
    h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_TITLE));

    msg = confirmObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
    //msg.appendChild(d.createTextNode(txt));
    msg.innerHTML = txt;

    btn = confirmObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
    btn.id = "closeBtn";
    btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT));
    btn.href = "#";
    btn.focus();
    btn.onclick = function() { removeCustomConfirm();return false; }

    confirmObj.style.display = "block";

}

function removeCustomConfirm() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("modalContainer"));
}
```

Comment: thank you  @Dario ..! i will try this.