# want to add style on alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to send a mail after registration but it is not working, I don't know what's wrong could plze help me out

**javascript**

```
// WRITE THE VALIDATION SCRIPT IN THE HEAD TAG.
function isNumber(evt) {
  var iKeyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
  if (iKeyCode != 46 && iKeyCode > 31 && (iKeyCode < 48 || iKeyCode > 57))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

**html + php**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form name="reg"  action="code_exec.php"  method="post">
      <table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <div align="center">
              <?php 
                $remarks=$_GET['remarks'];
                if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="") {
                  echo 'Register Here';
                }
                if ($remarks=='success') {
                  echo 'Registration Success';
                }
              ?>    
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="95"><div align="right">Mobile_no:</div></td>
          <td width="171"><input type="text" ID="tbNumbers" name="mobile_no" required maxlength="10" onkeypress="javascript:return isNumber(event)" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right">Name:</div></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" required/></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right">E_mail:</div></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="e_mail" E_MAIL required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
          <td><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div align="right"></div></td>
          <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I Want to send a mail after registration  the customer id which auto generated

```js
<?php
session_start();
$con       = mysqli_connect("retail", "RS", "orbisindia", "rs");
$mobile_no = $_POST['mobile_no'];
$name      = $_POST['name'];
$e_mail    = $_POST['e_mail'];
$password  = $_POST['password'];
$Cust_Id   = time();
$message   = "";
try {

        // execute the stored procedure
        $sql = mysqli_query($con,"CALL sp_retail_reg('$Cust_Id','$mobile_no','$name','$e_mail','$password')");
 if(!empty($Cust_Id)) {

$toEmail = $_POST['e_mail'];
$subject = "Thank you for registration";
$content = "your Custotmer id is" . $Cust_Id ;
    $content1 = "your Password is" . $password ; 
$mailHeaders = "From: rohit.jha@99rstreet.com";

if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $content,$content1, $mailHeaders)) {
    $message = "You have registered and your cutomer id  is sent to your email. plze check spam Also."; 
}
unset($_POST);
```

}

```
    } catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error occurred:" . $pe->getMessage());
    }
```

$message.="Your Cust_Id=$Cust_Id";
 echo "alert('$message'); window.location.href='home.php';";

Comment: plze overview my code and help me out with this  since i am new in this but i am trying

Comment: Please read this first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  You cannot simply dump all of your code here and tell us to fix it. Sorry, that is not how SO works.

Comment: i am not asking to fix it only i am asking where i am doing wrong and dont be sorry its my mistake

Comment: At least tell us what that actually means: "it is not working". Do you get an error? A blank page? Any entries in your http servers error log file? Any errors in your browsers javascript console? What does the "network" tab of your browsers development console show? Those are all things we cannot know, you have to tell us. We may be good, but we are not that good to magically guess what is wrong. And we hesitate to work through a wall of code when you can simply look at your error messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `window.location.href` from code_exec.php where `customerid` is alerted

```
echo "<script>alert('$message'); window.location.href='home.php';</script>"
```

which is redirecting to the home.php before calling the student_confirmation function.
You can write it after calling the student_confirmation function.

Comment: i want to change the stlye of alert how do i change help me with this code

Comment: i had change the code and it is working fine but i want to style alert box and how to do it

Comment: can anyone could fix it out

Comment: you need to use some Jquery popup plugins to have decorative styling for your messages.

Comment: try this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515471/how-to-add-style-sheet-to-confirm-box?rq=1

Comment: i tried this one but it is not working and even not showing any error could you plze do it thanks in advance